# Best data structure for searching record

Tags: perl, data-structures

I am having a lot of IDs and I want to store them for a temporary purpose and need to search that record for some operation. Which data structure is good for this operation in Perl?  Should I use a hash or an array, or is there any other module I could use to do this efficiently?

The records are `4343, 34343, 34343, 2323, 232, ...`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You may want to describe what kind of data you want to store and how you want to access it.

Comment: i have 10000 records and store  into one data strcuture and want to search those record

Comment: i am having IDs and reterive from d database and store into a one data strtucure and search some of records

Comment: Define 'search' - 'look up by ID' or 'find a match in the record's other fields'?

Comment: @Krish: Right from the start if you want to even check "Did I see this number?" a hash is more useful than an array. I mainly use arrays as 1) Lists and 2) a faster substitute for hashes where the keys only make sense as a tight range of numbers (i.e., not sparse arrays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little more information regarding your record layout would go a long way in helping people help you. If your records are linked to id numbers then you can use a hash with the 'id' as the key and store the record as a string or an array reference as the hash value

```
my %records;
$records{ $id_number } = "Record for $id_number";
## OR
$records{ $id_number } = ['Record', 'for', $id_number];
```

This will allow you to lookup id's with complexity O(1) and easily manipulate the corresponding record.

```
# Assuming the records are stored in @records
for my $record (@records) {
  $recStore{$record}++;
}

# To search for a record
my $recToFind = 4343;
my $recExists = $recStore{$recToFind} || 0;
```

The keys of the hash are the id's retrieved from your database and the corresponding values are the number of times the id was found, so for repeating records $recExists will be greater than 1, and for non-existent records it will be equal to 0. To get a list of all id's sorted numerically you could write

```
my @sortedID = sort {$a <=> $b} keys %records;
```

Comment: How to store and ids and search id .. for example . I want to search 4343  for the stored has. Could u please explain

Comment: Could you include the details of any one record? This would allow me to formulate a storage mechanism suited to the task.

Comment: I am getting the value in $Reocrd =10

Comment: And keep on getting different record whcih numeric and store to hash and some time in need to search some other numeric value with this hash